# How can i send a laravel email with SMTP without getting the .env data?

Tags: laravel, smtp

I need to fetch the SMTP data in the account of user that will be saved in the database. That way it couldn't pull the data from the .env file.

I'm using Laravel 8

For example, instead of looking for SMTP authentication in .env I would look in the database:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;
use Config;

use App\Mail\EmailManager;

class NewsletterController extends Controller
{
       
    public function testEmail(Request $request){
        $array['view'] = 'emails.newsletter';
        $array['subject'] = "SMTP Test";
        $array['from'] = 'email@email.com';
        $array['content'] = "This is a test email.";

        Config::set('mail.host', 'smtp.mailtrap.io');     
        Config::set('mail.username', 'email@email.com');     
        Config::set('mail.password', 'd13ea2a29a5cee');     
        Config::set('mail.port', 587);
 
        try {
            Mail::to($request->email)->send(new EmailManager($array));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
        }

        flash(translate('An email has been sent.'))->success();
        return back();
    }
}
```

I solved.

I Created a file with configutations:

/app/Providers/MailConfigServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Models\EmailSetting;
use Config;

class MailConfigServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
          if (\Schema::hasTable('email_settings')) {
            $mail = DB::table('email_settings')->first();
            if ($mail) //checking if table is not empty
            {
                $config = array(
                    'driver'     => $mail->driver,
                    'host'       => $mail->host,
                    'port'       => $mail->port,
                    'from'       => $mail->from,
                    'encryption' => $mail->encryption,
                    'username'   => $mail->username,
                    'password'   => $mail->password,
                    'sendmail'   => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
                    'pretend'    => false,
                );
                Config::set('mail', $config);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
         
    }
    
}
```

And added this line on app/config

```
App\Providers\MailConfigServiceProvider::class
```

Comment: To set configuration values at runtime, pass an array to the config helper:
Example for Laravel 9
config(['mail.mailer.smtp.transport' => 'Smtp']); do you have an error?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 8

Comment: This functionality is the same https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#determining-the-current-environment